# How to auto-populate referenced documents in a Sanity.io schema?

Tags: sanity

Here are the relationships I have:

Artists

Artworks -> references Artist from Artists

What I would like to do is view all the Artworks that reference a particular Artist inside the Artist Document view, without manually adding them. This way I can control custom sorting visually, and quickly see what artworks are associated with the Artist without having to reenter data.

I suspect I could use GROQ for this, but I don't know how to incorporate it into a schema for this purpose.